# Cannot locate currently running cron jobs

Tags: cron, centos7, cronolog

I know this is a dumb problem, but I cannot seem to locate/access a group of cron jobs that I have running (which I know are running, because everything is working properly and we can see the expected output of the scripts the crons are calling) on a CentOS server `CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503`

I set these cron jobs up well over 6 months ago on a server I don't regularly use, but I believe/recall that I just set them up using crontab in my home directory. But now, I cannot seem to find these crons anywhere on the server.

I'm my home directory I've tried:

```
crontab -u userName -l
```

and

```
crontab -l
```

And nothing shows up. So I listed running processes with `ps -xa` and got they showed up:

```
 9479 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/CROND -n
 9497 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c /home/local/UT/malvin/HHFB/HHFBUploader.py
 9498 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python /home/local/UT/malvin/HHFB/HHFBUploader.py
21043 ?        S      0:04 [kworker/u4:2]
27662 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/CROND -n
27671 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c /home/local/UT/malvin/HoopsHypeFB/HHFBUploader.p
27675 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python /home/local/UT/malvin/HHFB/HHFBUploa
28382 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/CROND -n
28389 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c /home/local/UT/malvin/FTFB/FTFBUploader.py >> 
28390 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/python/home/local/UT/malvin/FTFB/FTFBUploader.py
```

The lines with the Python files are the scripts being called by the crons jobs. When I checked crontab in the directories `/usr/sbin/` or `/bin/` nothing comes up. I also tried:

```
ls /etc/cron*
```

But nothing that looks like it pertains to these Python scripts comes up.

Answer (score 2):

The first place I would look is in the logs. Specifically `/var/log/cron`. That's the log file that the cron logs all it's activity to.

Answer (score 1):

One possible location for crontabs is `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.

Comment: When I cd into `/var/spool/cron/` I see `root` and `malvin` but I'm not what those are exactly, are they cron files?